# query SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this with the following code:

The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. I still searched the solution from this site but i can not found the what is the problem in my query. Anyone can help me here why i am getting =  **"The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"**  and How can i fix it  ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            S.created, 
            M.share_count, 
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads, 
            S.uid_fk AS 
            share_uid,
            S.ouid_fk AS share_ouid FROM 
            messages M, 
            users U, 
            friends F,
            message_share S 
            WHERE 
            F.friend_one='$uid' AND 
            U.uid = F.friend_one AND
            U.status='1' AND 
            F.friend_two != S.ouid_fk AND 
            M.uid_fk = S.ouid_fk AND F.role='fri' AND 
            S.msg_id_fk = M.msg_id group by msg_id)
            UNION
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            M.share_count,
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads, '0' AS share_uid, '0' AS share_ouid 
            FROM messages M, users U, friends F WHERE F.friend_one='$uid' AND U.status='1' AND M.uid_fk=U.uid AND M.uid_fk = F.friend_two GROUP by msg_id ) ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: Fix the subqueries so they have the same columns, lined up.  I think the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are doing an `UNION` and in that case both part of `SELECT` should contain exact same number of columns which isn't satisfying for your scenario. Your first `SELECT` part contains 10 selected columns whereas second `SELECT` statement contains only 9 columns and so the error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            S.created, 
            M.share_count, 
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads, 
            S.uid_fk AS 
            share_uid,
            S.ouid_fk AS share_ouid 
            FROM 
            messages M, 
            users U, 
            .........
            UNION
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            NOW() as created //Add some default value
            M.share_count,
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads, 
            '0' AS share_uid, 
            '0' AS share_ouid
```

Comment: i understand whay you mean. And i see the problem is definitely `S.created` line from the first `SELECT` section. But i really don't fined to solution for it. I need to use it but how can i use it from second `SELECT` statement ?

Comment: @innovation, if you can't select that column then try adding a default value column. See edit in answer if that helps. The same has been pointed out in another answer.

Comment: @raul i see it now. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both SELECT statements have to contain the same column count (created was missing in the second SELECT statement):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            S.created, 
            M.share_count, 
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads, 
            S.uid_fk AS 
            share_uid,
            S.ouid_fk AS share_ouid
 FROM messages M, users U, friends F, message_share S 
 WHERE F.friend_one='$uid'
 AND U.uid = F.friend_one
 AND U.status='1'
 AND F.friend_two != S.ouid_fk
 AND M.uid_fk = S.ouid_fk
 AND F.role='fri'
 AND S.msg_id_fk = M.msg_id
 GROUP BY msg_id

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
            M.msg_id, 
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message,
            '0000-00-00' as created
            M.share_count,
            U.username,
            U.last_login,
            M.uploads,
            '0' AS share_uid,
            '0' AS share_ouid 
 FROM messages M, users U, friends F
 WHERE F.friend_one='$uid'
 AND U.status='1'
 AND M.uid_fk=U.uid
 AND M.uid_fk = F.friend_two
 GROUP BY msg_id

 ORDER BY created DESC
```