# Can anyone help me fix my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database exists multiple tables, 6 of them are **category tables; baby_care, grocery, medical_equipment, medical_supply, medicine and personal_care** (pls nevermind the naming convention as this is our school project and we're still students).

I want to query their lotno and description attributes (which have differing names like med_lotno, etc.) along with their names and data from other tables like item_list and received_item. I need a single line query since, as we've observed, **jasperreport** query only accepts one line of query.

So I tried this query:

```
SELECT
all_items.il_code, 
"" & med_lotno & ms_lotno & pc_lotno & bc_lotno & gi_lotno as lotno, 
all_items.sup_name, 
me_description &  med_item_description & ms_item_description & pc_item_description & bc_description & gi_item_description as description, 
"" & med_expdate & ms_expdate & pc_expdate & bc_expdate & gi_expdate as expiration_date, 
all_items.ri_unit_quantity, 
all_items.ri_date from 
((((((select il_code from item_list union 
select sup_name from supplier union 
select ri_unit_quantity, ri_date from received_item) as all_items 
left join medical_equipment ON (all_items.il_code = medical_equipment.il_code))
left join medicine ON (all_items.il_code = medicine.il_code)) 
left join medical_supply ON (all_items.il_code = medical_supply.il_code))
left join personal_care ON (all_items.il_code = personal_care.il_code))
left join baby_care ON (all_items.il_code = baby_care.il_code))
left join grocery ON (all_items.il_code = grocery.il_code);
```

But it gives me an error

> "java.sql.SQLException: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query SELECT statements have a different number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169193/query-select-statements-have-a-different-number-of-columns)

Comment: Looks like you are using `Ms-Access` but you tagged all the other databases

Comment: Fixing this might not be the best approach. Starting afresh may prove more fruitful. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the sql now, but I think I found the precise part that is  throwing this particular error. The union statement needs each select to have the same number of columns and one of them has two. See below.

```
SELECT
    all_items.il_code, 
    "" & med_lotno & ms_lotno & pc_lotno & bc_lotno & gi_lotno as lotno, 
    all_items.sup_name, 
    me_description &  med_item_description & ms_item_description & pc_item_description & bc_description & gi_item_description as description, 
    "" & med_expdate & ms_expdate & pc_expdate & bc_expdate & gi_expdate as expiration_date, 
    all_items.ri_unit_quantity, 
    all_items.ri_date 
FROM
(
  select il_code from item_list union
  select sup_name from supplier union
  select ri_unit_quantity, ri_date from received_item #<---This select here has two columns while the other selects in the union have only one.
) as all_items 
left join medical_equipment ON all_items.il_code = medical_equipment.il_code
left join medicine ON all_items.il_code = medicine.il_code
left join medical_supply ON all_items.il_code = medical_supply.il_code
left join personal_care ON all_items.il_code = personal_care.il_code
left join baby_care ON all_items.il_code = baby_care.il_code
left join grocery ON all_items.il_code = grocery.il_code;
```

Without really changing the functionality of your query you could change the unioned selects to:

```
select il_code, "" from item_list union
select sup_name, "" from supplier union
select ri_unit_quantity, ri_date from received_item
```

This way they all have the same number of columns and the only drawback is that there will be some empty fields in the results table. Admittedly, I have never seen left joins nested in this particular way.